# How do you configure C# projects to build using Windows SDK 7.1 tools?

Tags: c#, windows, sdk, managed

We're trying to switch a lot of projects over to use SDK7.1. This seems pretty straightforward with C++ projects, and you can change the 'Platform Toolset' property in the project settings to "Windows7.1SDK" and all is good.

But, with C# projects, (if you put the build output up to diagnostic mode), we can see that various tools such as sgen, resgen, LC, run from within a previous SDK 7.0A directory. Or, on some machines that we installed Vistual Studio 2012 on, some of these tools come from an v8.0A SDK folder.

Mismatches between the tools and the assemblies they produce seem to be causing various errors such as:

```
LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly
'S:\Libraries\Bin\Release\Some.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.'
```

It seems we can edit the .csproj files and almost ad-hoc, and BeforeBuild etc targets that redefine various SDKPath properties. This seems to force the right tools to be used. But, if feels very 'hacky'. And we must be missing setting something as we still get some errors.

Alternatively, we've found, we can change the registry value here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0\SDK40ToolsPath
```

to point at the correct SDK. But, it feels wrong to have to modify the environment to support this. We want to build old versions of our product, and having to switch the environment around to do this is ugly and error prone.

Is there any official way of doing this?

Thanks.

P.S. I found this question http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/windowssdk/thread/ebc8914f-d4b5-44e7-8c76-10332d155812 where the poster seems to be asking a similar thing, but, the question didn't seem to get answered.

Answer (score 1):

The following two articles talk about defining custom tool sets. Perhaps one of those needs defining for the 7.1 SDK, and then MSBuild can be directed to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397428.aspx